# Fill mysql column if two tables has the same value

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables, both has 3 columns, the first table third column is empty, the second table third column has data.

### Table 1

```
---------|------------|---------|
codprc   | numideent  |  Empty  |
---------|------------|---------|
20000002 | 890300604  |         |
20000002 | 800077226  |         |
20000003 | 890300604  |         |
20000003 | 79692317   |         |
20000003 | 22802672   |         |<-----
20000005 | 240284866  |         |
20000005 | 20310518   |         |
20000005 | 17189852   |         |
20000005 | 17118956   |         |
20000005 | 41496516   |         |
20000005 | 20713128   |         |
20000005 | 19142900   |         |
```

### Table2

```
---------|------------|----------|
icodprc  | inumideent | icodcpe  |
---------|------------|----------|
20000003 | 22802672   |    3     |<------
20000003 | 79692317   |    3     |
20000003 | 890300604  |    4     |
20000003 | 890300604  |    4     |
20000005 | 17118956   |    4     |
20000005 | 17189852   |    4     |
20000005 | 19142900   |    4     |
20000005 | 20284866   |    4     |
20000005 | 20310518   |    4     |
20000005 | 20713128   |    3     |
20000005 | 41496516   |    4     |
20000007 | 890300604  |    4     |
20000008 | 890300604  |    4     |
20000009 | 41462678   |    4     |
20000009 | 860351432  |    3     |
20000010 | 890300604  |    4     |
```

I need the first table 3rd column to be populated with the second table 3rd column But just if fisrt and secod column of both tables are equal.

For example, the values tale2.icodprc and table2.inumideent 1st row are equal to table1.codprc table1.numideent 5th row, so the value of icodcpe must be fill the empty column at row 5th.

I have tried several options but I think I am missing something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax to join the tables:

```
UPDATE Table1
  JOIN Table2
    ON Table2.icodprc    = Table1.codprc
   AND Table2.inumideent = Table1.numideent
SET    Table1.Empty      = Table2.icodcpe
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9601d/1/0).

Comment: Thank you it works, I didn't know the update join syntax. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Does this work ?

```
UPDATE Table1 
   SET Empty = (SELECT icodcpe 
                  FROM Table2 
                 WHERE Table1.codprc = Table2.icodprc
                   AND Table1.numideent = Table2.inumideent)
```

Comment: No, I already tried the same but the Subquery returns more than 1 row